# Snakemake delete output files from master node if cluster job gets killed

Tags: slurm, snakemake

I am running snakemake on the login node of a cluster using the slurm job queuing system.

Unfortunately, if a slurm job times out, or if it gets killed with `scancel`, the snakemake script inside the job does not delete the output files, since it gets killed as well.

The master snakemake process however stays alive in these circumstances, so I would like this process to delete the output files of the failed child jobs. Is there an option for that, or some hack that does this?

Comment: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52500725/snakemake-hangs-when-cluster-slurm-cancelled-a-job

Comment: Thank you @Maarten-vd-Sande. While I solved the issue the person in that question had, my issue is different. But it is apparently also a bug in snakemake: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/627

Anyways, if someone has an idea or experience of how to work around this until it gets resolved, I would be very thankful.

Comment: I made a pull request for this issue now, let's hope it gets merged soon: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/pull/857