# Snakemake workflow process stuck - waiting for jobs executed on SLURM cluster

Tags: bioinformatics, slurm, snakemake

I have a problem with executing a Snakemake workflow and hopefully you could help me out.
Everything is fine if I run the pipeline on a local machine. However, sometimes (not always) when I specify to execute rules on a SLURM computational cluster it can happen that the workflow gets "stuck". Please look at the attached image below - the process says it waits until all jobs finish so that it can proceed further with downstream steps. However, when I check with `squeue` all my jobs indeed finished and the output files are already there(!) It is just that the main process "did not get the notification back"... In such cases I have to kill it manually, unlock the snakemake dir and rerun the pipeline.

[image]

I use Snakemake `5.19.0`; My execution command:

```
snakemake \
    --snakefile="../Snakefile" \
    --configfile="../configs/config.yml" \
    --cluster-config "../configs/cluster_config.json" \
    --use-singularity \
    --cores 128 \
    --local-cores 2 \
    --printshellcmds \
    --verbose \
    --latency-wait 120 \
    --cluster \
    "sbatch \
    --cpus-per-task={cluster.threads} \
    --mem={cluster.mem} \
    --qos={cluster.queue} \
    --time={cluster.time} \
    --output={params.LOG_cluster_log}-%j-%N.log \
    -p XXX" \
    --singularity-args "--no-home --bind ${PWD}/.."
```

Comment: This could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52500725/snakemake-hangs-when-cluster-slurm-cancelled-a-job